# Assigning multiple values to a single planning entity instance

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on a project in OptaPlanner which is close to the nurse roster example. Besides assigning the employees to shifts i also need to assign the employees to small assignments within the shift. The required number of employees that need to be assigned to the small assignments is not an integer it is a rational number , and every employee besides having a skill (that is required by the small assignment) has a performance meter for that skill that is also a rational number.So the employees needed to meet the required number can be variable based on their performance ,and i can't create N different instances of the small assignment and let OptaPlanner assign an employee to it.

Is there a way to create a single instance of the small assignment ,and have something like a list where employees can be added or removed and the required number is changed accordingly based on the performance that the employee has for that small assignment,in other words can the planning variable be a list that contains the employees assigned?

Comment: Relates to [https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-167](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-167)

Comment: Usually, docs section "4.3.1. Is This Class a Problem Fact or Planning Entity?" works around this, because in most cases assigning multiple values to a single variable is undesirable (because there is no clear limit on how many to assign - and if there is, then a finer grained domain model is a better solution).

Comment: Thanks i will try to go around it and make a better model.